# airplay audio from iPhone to MacBook Pro?

Tags: airplay

Is it possible at all to airplay audio from an iPhone to a MacBook Pro?
that is play from iPhone but select the output to be the MBP speakers instead of the airPods or internal speaker of the phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking about a native way to do this from macOS, or with third party apps?

As far as I know **there is no way to arbitrarily play AirPlay audio to macOS**, but your macOS devices can show up as recipients for some things like phone calls (by selecting the speaker button during a call).

On the third party side of things, there are a couple of apps for macOS that claim to allow this (I have not tested any of these personally).  Check out [AirServer](https://www.airserver.com/Mac) and [Reflector](https://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector).  From their website, AirServer seems to have a lot of features, and compatibility for more than just AirPlay.  AirServer has a [trial](https://www.airserver.com/Download) and a discount for students, so that's where I would start if I were in need.  Additionally, I couldn't find if Reflector supports streaming just audio, but AirServer supports [lossless audio](https://www.airserver.com/Usage/Entertainment#allfeatures) AirPlay playback.

Comment: Reflector does support audio-only streaming. Choose the Mac as an Airplay destination, and it works.

Comment: thx so much tested air server and its perfect